# How to avoid writing some machines I listening to a file without losing information using FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, winforms

I am running into an issue with a `FileSystemWatcher`.
I listen to a certain text file and each new line (FileSystemWatcher.Changed) is handle.
`Text file` that I listen to it is on the local network and some computers can write to the file at the same time.
When a particular machine writing my text file I immediately take the last line in the file and handles it.
How can I verify if for example some machines write to the file at the same time that i took this string from each machine without miss ?

This is my class:

```
public class Watcher
{
    private string _file;

    public Watcher(string file)
    {
        _file = file;
    }

    public void startWatch()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName(_file);
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName(_file);
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Changed += watcher_Changed;
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    public void watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        readLastLine();
    }

    private void readLastLine()
    {
        string lastLine = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
        {
            string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
            int x = str.LastIndexOf('\n');
            lastLine = str.Substring(x + 1);
        }

        validateString(lastLine);
    }

    private void validateString(string str)
    {
        string[] arr = str.Split(' ');

        if (arr.Length != 2 && arr[0] != "start" && arr[0] != "stop" && arr[0] != "finish")
            return;

        // Handle the string...
    }
}
```

Comment: you can't, you need a different more robust solution to such requirment, `FileSystemWatcher` won't do, what if your computer disconnects from the network (just a most obvious maybe not too realistic but possiable scenario ..)

Comment: Maybe Client that send string to server will be more reliable ?

Comment: Definetly. not to mention that when experimenting with `FileSystemWatcher` awhile ago it was dropping events on the same machine! there is other way to watch files (although all come from windows instumentation apis) but they are again not reliable